# query_posts sort in multiple directions

Tags: query-posts, customization, sort

I'm trying to improve my post sorting by using multiple criteria, but I want specific orders for different values. For example, I have a meta_key called 'featured' that I want to move any post up to the top. For matching 'featured', it should sort by title.

The problem is that I can only define one "order" key in the query_posts function.

```
$args=array(
                                        'post_type'         => 'portfolio-item',
                                        'post_status'       => 'publish',
                                        'caller_get_posts'  => 1,
                                        'paged'             => $paged,
                                        'meta_key'          => 'featured',
                                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value title',
                                        'order'             => 'desc asc',
                                    );
```

This is the parameter array I'd like to use (notice the multiple order values. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the correct form. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to provide all of the same arguments (with the exception of maybe a variable name being different) for `query_posts`, `new WP_Query` _and_ `get_posts`.

Comment: I sorted it out by getting all posts and sorting manually. I still don't think any of those query solutions provide multiple sorting directions.

Comment: Oh, well they do. But I think you haven't turned all the funky PHP and WP debug/error handling on and missing the notes.

Answer (score 1):

### OrderBy

The query functions, like `get_posts()`, `query_posts()` call a `new WP_Query` inside - they're just wrappers.

The more important thing is what goes on in the `class WP_Query`. Specifically inside `WP_Query -> get_posts()`. When you add an `orderby` argument, then the following happens:

1. WP checks if it set. If not, then it uses the `$wpdb->posts.post_date` and appends the `order value to it.
2. If you set it to `'none'`, then there's *no* order applied.
3. In every other case, the order will be used.

**But**... there're "allowed orderby" values:

```
$allowed_keys = array('name', 'author', 'date', 'title', 'modified', 'menu_order', 'parent', 'ID', 'rand', 'comment_count');
```

For meta key/value pairs, there's a *special* case: If the meta key isn't empty, the `meta_key` value is added to the allowed keys, as well as `meta_value` and `meta_value_num`.

The function than explodes the `orderby` string to an array and loops through. Everything that matches gets added to a new array, which is then imploded (separated by a comma) after the loop and added to the SQL query string. If the resulting array was empty, then - again - the `"$wpdb->posts.post_date"` followed by the `order` will be taken. If that is empty too, then you'll see the same result as with `none`.

So if you're adding anything like a meta key and a meta value, then you should get the following added to your query:

```
"$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value,$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value,$wpdb->posts.post_title"
```

### Post Type(s)

Your post type arg gets added to the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
 AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'portfolio-item'
```

### What I think is wrong in here:

1. You can't add `asc desc` as `order` statement. The order **must be** either `ASC` **or** `DESC` (upper-/lowercase doesn't matter). This won't work and will likely break.
2. I'm pretty sure, that `'portfolio-item'` isn't the actual post type name. I guess it's just `portfolio`. Be sure to call whatever the post type is named inside

   ```
   var_dump( array_keys( (array) $GLOBALS['wp_post_types'] ) );
   ```
3. `caller_get_posts` is a pre 3.1 argument. You should already get a note at the top/beginning of your code, as the following `_deprecated_argument()` is called *before* any query string is even built:

   ```
   "caller_get_posts" is deprecated. Use "ignore_sticky_posts" instead.
   ```