# meta_query sorting by 2 keys

Tags: meta-query

I need to sort (custom) posts by 2 custom field values...

custom field name 1: `is_sponsored` [ value can either be `1` or `0` ]

custom field name 2: `sfp_date` [ `timestamp` aka current post date in seconds ]

Posts whose "`is_sponsored`" value is 1 need to be on top, sorted by "`sfp_date`" in `DESC`ending order.
All other posts whose "`is_sponsored`" value is 0 should be listed below - in descending order (by "`sfp_date`") as well.

I have something like:

```
$sfp_query_args = array(
    'tax_query'   => array( 
        array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'sfp_posts',
            'terms'    => array( 1, 5, 8 )
        )
    ),
    'post_type'   => 'sfpposts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts'   => 15,
    'paged'       => $paged,
    'meta_key'    => 'sfp_date', 
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order'       => 'DESC', 
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'key'          => 'is_sponsored',
        'value'        => 2,
        'type'         => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare'      => '<='
    )
);
$wp_q = new WP_Query( $sfp_query_args );
```

...but not working. Any ideas?

---

*Editors Note:* This is a small plugin that should show how the query looks, as we likely don't have any data set available to test this.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#67600) Dump Query parts */
function wpse67600_dump_query_parts( $pieces )
{
    echo '<pre>'.var_export( $pieces, true ).'</pre>';
    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse67600_dump_query_parts' );
```

*OP PLEASE ADD OUTPUT OF PLUGIN HERE - use the "edit" link*.

### EDIT by Dameer

OK, after tracing request and numerous workarounds, I've come up with the following...

If I simplify "$sfp_query_args" a little bit the result is close to what's required, however, inability to sort posts remains as is. Here it is:

```
$sfp_query_args1 = array(
    'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'sfp_post_category', 'terms' => $cat_id_arr ) ),
    'post_type' => 'sfpposts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts' => (int)$per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'is_sponsored', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value date'
);
```

- *orderby takes two attributes: meta_value and date*

So $wpdb->request with above arguments in query looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $wpdb->posts.ID 
FROM $wpdb->posts 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships 
ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta 
ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'sfpposts' 
AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') 
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'is_sponsored' ) 
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID 
ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, $per_page
```

And finally, in order to be able to sort by meta_value as well, query  should be set with only one minor difference:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $wpdb->posts.ID 
FROM $wpdb->posts 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships 
ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta 
ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'sfpposts' 
AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish') 
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'is_sponsored' ) 
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID 
ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value [!ORDER MISSING!], $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, $per_page
```

Please spot [!ORDER MISSING!] placeholder. I guess the above should explain where exactly the problem occurs.

Comment: I don't believe you **can** do that with default WP_Query class. Even in the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) it says "Do you know how to sort the query if the meta_value is an array? Write it here". You will probably have to write your own SQL query for this.

Comment: Yeap, I know it hasn't been resolved yet but I thought this is the right place to sort it out :)

Comment: I've added a small plugin to your question, so you can show us the final SQL query parts. Please edit your question with that info. Thanks.

Comment: Oh and [**here is some info**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40138/query-posts-sort-in-multiple-directions/67091#67091) from a related question about **how sorting** works in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the final workaround would be to split query:

```
$sfp_query_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'sfp_post_category', 'terms' => $cat_id_arr ) ),
    'meta_key' => 'is_sponsored',
    'post_type' => 'sfpposts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts' => (int)$per_page,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

...and use "posts_orderby" filter to modify ORDER part:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'sfp_modify_orderby' );
function sfp_modify_orderby( $orderby ) {
    if( !is_admin() && is_tax( 'sfp_post_category' ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby = " $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value DESC, $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC ";
    }
    return $orderby;
}
```

The most probably you'll need to remove filter after the loop on page in order to prevent 'posts_orderby' affect any other query (sidebar or footer). So here's another function to put in "functions.php":

```
function sfp_remove_orderby_filter() {
    remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'sfp_modify_orderby' );
}
```

...and on the page using our query discard filter:

```
if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // code
endwhile;
else :
    // code
endif;

sfp_remove_orderby_filter();
```

Hopefully it makes sense!

Answer (score -1):

I am writing your query modifying slightly. I hope it may help.

```
$sfp_query_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'sfp_posts', 'terms' => array( 1, 5, 8) ) ),
    'post_type' => 'sfpposts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts' => 15,
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'meta_key'=>'sfp_date', 
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'sfp_date',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'is_sponsored',
        'value' => '2',
        'compare' => '<='
    )       
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
$wp_q = new WP_Query( $sfp_query_args );
```

Please let me know whether it works or not :-)

Comment: This would default sort (by date), since you don't provide 'meta_key'.

Comment: Thank you @MihaRekar, It was a mistake thanks for your correction

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work, it just keeps sorting posts by date without putting those who have "is_sponsored" value of 1 to the top.

Comment: I am looking into finding a solution to this. May be @MihaRekar is right. You may have to write custom sql query for this

Comment: Is there a way you can provide an example of "normal" mySQL query?