# Set right order for query that returns posts based on two custom fields

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

My query arguments are inspired by a [solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126772/query-to-sort-a-list-by-meta-key-first-if-it-exists-and-show-remaining-posts#answer-126928). I needed to get posts with custom field `expert_intown` but I also needed to exclude posts that have the meta_key `coming_soon`. My arguments works fine, as in it returns the posts as expected.

Now, I need help to get the results in right order, that is I need the posts with the field `expert_intown` to appear **before** the posts with the custom-field `coming_soon`. I have been trying for a while and currently I have this argument, which again fails.

```
$intown_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat'  => 2,
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status'  =>  'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                                   'relation' => 'OR',
                                array( //posts that contain the meta_key expert_intown 
                                   'key' => 'expert_intown',
                                   'value' => 'yes',
                                   'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                                ),
                                array( //posts that dont contain the meta_key coming_soon
                                   'key' => 'coming_soon',
                                   'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                )
                            ),
            'meta_key' => 'expert_intown',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'DESC'
            ); 

            $int_pro = new WP_Query( $intown_args );
```

NOTE : This query works fine with `'orderby' => title or date`, just fails to group together the posts containing the field `'expert_intown'`.

---

Also please note that every value of `expert_intown` is set to `yes`, perhaps the reason to fail, as I may be trying to order by values which are all equal. But even in that case **shouldn't it be grouped together** ?, because right now the posts with the field `expert_intown` are mixed with posts with field `coming_soon`.

---

**UPDATE FIRST** :
As a shot in the dark, I tried the `posts_orderby` filter as [suggested in a solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67600/meta-query-sorting-by-2-keys/#67726). Hopefully to get posts by meta_value and then date, but does not seem to work either. Here is now what the code looks like with the filter.

```
$intown_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat'  => 2,
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status'  =>  'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(  
                                   'key' => 'expert_intown',
                                   'value' => 'yes',
                                   'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                                ),
                                array( 
                                   'key' => 'coming_soon',
                                   'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                )
                            )
            ); 

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'modify_orderby' );
function modify_orderby( $orderby ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby = " $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value DESC, $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC ";
        return $orderby;
}
$int_pro = new WP_Query( $intown_args );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'modify_orderby' );
```

Comment: Just a thought...if the 'expert_intown' part of the OR is true, it may or may not have something in 'coming_soon' as well, that's probably why the results are mixed.  Just because you sort on the 'expert_intown' value, that won't cause the rows with a 'coming_soon' value to be moved to the bottom.  The rows that have a 'yes' for 'expert_intown' will display whatever value is present in that row for 'coming_soon'. Maybe I'm reading your question wrong but perhaps you should use AND instead of OR and possibly use two separate loops.

Comment: using the AND **WILL** only return posts with the field expert_intown because the args will be 'expert_intown' exists and 'coming_soon' doesn't.  The args are returning exactly what they should.  For the second loop try returning 'expert_intown' AND 'coming_soon' exist and a possible needed third loop would be 'coming_soon' exists AND 'expert_intown' does NOT.

Comment: Any luck, @gurung?

Comment: @leromt With relation - `AND`, and both 'expert_intown' and 'coming_soon' set to EXIST - returns no post at all. With same settings but the relation - `OR`, returns posts only that contains both those meta fields, avoiding the ones that are empty.

Comment: @leromt With relation - `AND`, wherein 'coming_soon - EXISTS'  and 'expert_intown - NOT EXISTS, returns nothing.